# SQL query: SELECT * FROM table WHERE private = 0 "unless" user = 'username'

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to have query that would select from the database all the information which is private = 0 unless the user = 'username'

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE private = 0 "unless" user = 'username'
```

Comment: What if I want to choose where private = 0 unless private = 1 and user = 'username'

Comment: Now that's a completely different question :(  You need to make sure you know what you want before asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to original question:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE private = 0 
and user <> 'username'
```

**EDIT**: OP added the following comment:

> What if I want to choose where private = 0 unless private = 1 and user = 'username'

Then it sounds like you simply want this (but it's not 100% clear):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE private = 0 
OR (private = 1 and user = 'username')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE private = 0 AND user != 'username';
```

This version assumes that `user` is not `NULL`.

You might find it easier to interpret as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE private = 0 AND NOT (user = 'username');
```

Comment: @Legionar: Why did you change the *not equals* operator?

Comment: First I thought, that only `!=` is working in `mysql`, but now I see, also `<>` is working. My fault.

Comment: @gordon linoff, if user column having null value at that time in where condition we should use isnull(user, '') !=  'username' in SQL server?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE private = 0 AND user != 'username'
```

Comment: This is wrong answer, in this case database returns rows where "private" and "user", not private unless "user"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE private = 0 AND user != 'username'
```

Comment: That's the opposite. OP wants rows where user <> username.

Comment: This is wrong answer, in this case database returns rows where private and user, not private unless user...before your edit..